# Accessing variables in gradle buildscript block

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm attempting to not have any usernames and passwords in plain text in my project.
I came across this plugin: https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-credentials-plugin

While it works great outside the buildscript block, I'm unable to access the variables within the buildscript block. Based on my understanding this could be because the buildscript block is executed first and therefore the variables have not yet been defined.

Is that just the limitation of this plugin? If so, what would be the best way to achieve encrypting credentials within the buildscript block?

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        credentialsPluginVersion = "3.0"
    }
    
    repositories {

    maven {
            url "https://privatenexusrepo.com/repository/privatereleases/"
            credentials {
                username storedUsername
                password storedPassword
           }
    }        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("nu.studer:gradle-credentials-plugin:${credentialsPluginVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "nu.studer.credentials"

def storedUsername = credentials.forKey('storedUsername')
def storedPassword = credentials.forKey('storedPassword')

println "Username: " + storedUsername
println "Password: " + storedPassword
```